# Illustrator: transparent shapes used as highlights are visible

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Looking for some help rasterizing / flattening a complex image.

Here is the image in Illustrator as it should look, placed on a white background.

[image: correct display of image in question]

The image needs to ultimately remain a vector EPS that can be placed on different backgrounds, etc. However, when it is placed on a coloured background, the shapes and paths I overlaid to create highlights are visible. Here is the image moved off of the art board so you can see it set on the grey:

[image: image on grey]

How do I rasterize / blend the shapes so that they do not appear and simply function as a highlight effect?

This is the file: http://hospitalgrade.net/media/object-blue%20grad-highlight%20adjust.rar

Answer (score 1):

Note that based upon the file it *could* be cleaned up to remain vector and retain the appearance without the use of blending modes (which are why teh white appears n dark backgrounds). Unfortunately, explaining *how* one would go about that in any sort of procedural fashion would require perhaps an hour long video seminar or a 30 page message board post. It's simply not feasible to explain, especially in this format.

The short answer...

- Isolate sections, expand them, crop to remove clipping paths... repeat.
- In areas where blending modes create the appearance, add additional *fills* with a color variance rather than a blending mode to achieve the same overall appearance.

Option 2....

- Create a new path to use as a clipping path or opacity mask for the entire shape.

Answer (score 0):

i think the white's are additional stroke. just remove them in appearance panel. try also removing stray points. If none of these works highlight all paths or lines; expand all fill and stroke; select same black fill/stoke merge or unite them/ group them; then remove other colors except black.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

When I remove the stroke from the white "highlight" shapes in the appearance panel, the shape / stroke disappears, but so does the intended highlight effect that it was meant to have on the paths beneath it.

perhaps a better place to begin would be to ask the question - How do you give a thin line a highlight / shimmer effect with an opacity mask?  It's obvious that overlaying a shape larger or thicker than the line below it leaves you with the mask shape visible and overlapping?

Comment: Here is the file in question:
http://hospitalgrade.net/media/object-blue%20grad-highlight%20adjust.rar

Comment: Sorry I cannot open it in mac. So you have fixed it?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Instead of using shapes with opacity masks to achieve the "highlight" effect on the thin lines, I added a layer and drew in very fine light lines manually here and there to mimic the effect.